# VBscript codebehind to javascript

Tags: javascript, com, vbscript, vb6

I have a page that is getting information sent to it from a com+ component, this component is sending vbscript which does not work in any other browsers then IE.

Trying to convert this part so that it sends a javascript instead, but I do not know how.

```
Response.Write "<td><button onclick='VBScript: SelectNr """ & rs("Nr") & """,""" & rs("Project") & """,""" & rs("Nr") & """,""" & rs("MainNr") & """ ,""" & rs("Workplace") & """ ' onfoc='foc' onblur='unfoc' >Select</button></td>"
```

Comment: Have you, you know, *tried* anything? Experimented? That's what developers are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

On event handler, change `VBScript` literal with `javascript` or just delete it, and enclose the function argument list in parenthesis . But, what `SelectNr` is? if it is vbscript code, this will also need to be converted.

Comment: Changing `VBScript` to `javascript` won't really work since the two are syntactically incompatible.

Comment: Yes. VBScript method invocation does not use parenthesis. Javascript does. So, making the indicated changes in onclick handler `the call` will be correct. BUT, as said, if `SelectNr` method is written in VBScript it needs to be rewritten in javascript.